# How to align functions in an array with a curly bracket?

Tags: arrays

As titel states. My code looks like this:

```
\begin{equation*}
F_{v,Rk}=\left \{
    \begin{array}{r1}
    & f_{h,1,k} \cdot t_1 \cdot d \\
    & 0.5 \cdot f_{h,2,k} \cdot t_2 \cdot d \\ 
    & 1.05 \dfrac{f_{h,1,k} \cdot t_1 \cdot d}{2+\beta} [\sqrt{2\beta (1+\beta)+\dfrac{4\cdot\beta(2+\beta)M_{y,Rk}}{f_{h,1,k}d t_1^2}}-\beta]+\dfrac{F_{ax,Rk}}{4} \\
    & 1.15\sqrt{\dfrac{2\beta}{1+\beta}}\sqrt{2M_{y,Rk} f_{h,1,k} d}+\dfrac{F_{ax,Rk}}{4} \\
    \end{array} \right
\end{equation*}
```

This gives this result:
[image]

I want it to look like this:

[image]

Anyone have an idea of how to solve this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please edit your query to show not a screenshot of LaTeX code, but the code itself.

Comment: I tried doing so. It deleted all pictures, but I reckon you can use the links in the bottom? - Thanks!

Comment: and make this into a full but minimal self contained documnent that others can copy and test as is. Here we have to guess document class and preamble and that usually ends bad. Help us help you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the screenshot of your code block, the line

```
\begin{array}{r1}
```

is surely wrong, as `1` ("one") is not recognized as a valid column type. You should be getting warning messages to this effect, say, `LaTeX Error: Illegal character in array arg`.

I assume you intended to use the `l` ("ell") column type and hence meant to write

```
\begin{array}{rl} % "ell", not "one"
```

However, you should really be thinking about pursuing a different approach altogether. I suggest you load the `mathtools` package for its `dcases` environment and rewrite your code block as follows:

```
\[
F_{v,Rk}=\min
\begin{dcases}
row1\\
row2\\
row3\\
\dots\\
row(n-1)\\
rown
\end{dcases}
\]
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Worked like a charm!